# How do I randomize the ordering of results from a Rails finder method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, random

I’m using Rails 4 and a Postgres database.  For a particular table, I want to serve a bunch of table records to a user, but in a randomized order.  Further, I don’t want to display all the data at once, but rather would prefer the user page through it.  So if the randomized order for all the data has IDs

```
10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1
```

I would want the data with IDs

```
10, 8, 6, 4, 2
```

to be displayed on page 1 and the data with ids 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 to be displayed on page 2 (assuming each page has five results).  How do I write a finder method that will randomize the data in such a way or how do I take the results of a finder method and randomize their ordering?  Note that the initial group of records won’t be everything in the table (it will be everything with the enabled field set to true).

Comment: Related question with different database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447465/where-to-order-a-result-set-randomly-in-database-or-in-memory

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can randomize query results with `order("random()")`, e.g.

```
SomeModel.where(enabled: true).order("random()")
```

to return all `SomeModel`s in random order.

As you're probably thinking, if you do that once with `offset(0).limit(5)` for the first page and again with `offset(5).limit(5)` for the second page, you'll get a different random order the second time and pagination will not make sense.

I would address this by caching the query results. For example, with Rails caching:

```
results = Rails.cache.fetch("some_models/#{current_user.id}")
  SomeModel.where(enabled: true).order("random()")
end
```

You can then slice the results according to what page you're on.

Since all this requires you to load all the models (or all the models returned by some query) into memory, you might as well shuffle them in memory:

```
results = Rails.cache.fetch("some_models/#{current_user.id}")
  SomeModel.where(enabled: true).shuffle
end
```

That allows your database to cache the underlying query results, which `random()` prevents.